# Unable to change rules of React Bootsrap using CSS Modules

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-css-modules

I am trying to change the background color of a react-bootstrap list group item.

My example.js file

```
import {classes} from "./Sidebar.module.css";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import React from "react"; 
const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ListGroup>
                <ListGroup.Item className = {classes.Color} >Products</ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>Stores</ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Sidebar.module.css file has

```
.Color{
    background-color: red;
```

Even after giving a custom class name, the background color is still the default color.

Comment: If you remove the curly braces ```{}``` around css import name then it itself should be fine I believe.. Like this ```import classes from "./Sidebar.module.css";``` Here you go, https://codesandbox.io/s/css-modules-react-cq6nj .. Instead of ```Sidebar.module.css``` , you find the same in ```styles.module.css``` so you can adjust those changes in your css.. Does this helps you??

Comment: Hi, @ManirajMurugan Thank you.  Even after removing the `{}` It still doesn't change the background color and other styles unless I use `!important`, which is hard to use for each style.

Comment: In the codesandbox link provided above, I have not included any ```! important``` .. Can you fork the codesandbx given above and reproduce your issue?? I will try for the solution..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a default color use !important. Also remove curly braces when you load styles from Sidebar.module.css. Like this

```
import classes from './Sidebar.module.css';

.Color {
   background-color: red !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Is there a way to not use !important as there are many rules that act this way?

Comment: If you just remove the  curly braces than you don't need to use !important.

Comment: Also you need to make sure that your css selector has highest specificity.